# Upgrading OData to v3

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

I have a WCF Data service that I just upgraded to V3 (from V2). What is the best way to not break existing clients?

Note that some clients use .Net < 4

Answer (score 0):

You will not break you current client as long as they correctly send their MaxDataServiceVersion request header. So basically the client can tell the server what version it wants to work with.

Comment: Did you mean you upgraded to v3 bits or you changed the MaxProtocolVersion in the service to V3? If you just upgraded to v3 bits, that should be fine. If you changed the configuration to V3, then the question is why did you change it to V3 - there must be some feature that you wanted to use?

Comment: yes, the latter one. Query over 1..n is a great feature of V3. (its any: and all: lambda-like query parameters to $select)